# Image onload event after image has loaded

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events

I have a script that attaches onload event handlers to all the images on a page, however because it's a GreaseMonkey script it can only run after the images are there, so some of them may have already loaded, is there a way to trigger the onload event if the image is already loaded?

Comment: This solution is ... suboptimal. If you already have the image loaded why would you reattach it again and wait for another load? This would slow down your website imo

Comment: Have you considered inlining some code to set a variable in the image dataset that the image load has been completed? Then at the start of your script check this dataset variable for all images and handle the onload event only for the ones that have not yet loaded. I can write a full answer if you need more clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not adverse to using a framework such as jQuery, there's a triggerHandler() function that should do what you need.

You'll need a test to check whether or not the image has been loaded in your script (should be able to find details on how to do this using Google) - if it hasn't been loaded, simply attach the onload event handler; if it has been loaded, you can either attach the onload event handler and then trigger it using jQuery's triggerHandler() function, or execute the code/function that would have been executed by the onload event handler - which is easiest likely depends on what your onload event handler does.

Comment: For some reason I can't edit the question but what I wanted was a way to attach an event that'll either trigger when the image loads, or if the image is already loaded will run right away

Comment: @Bugster I've edited my answer to include some extra information on how you could go about doing this.

Comment: That would have been a good solution, but I've already got one, maybe I'll implement it later

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I know it's been a while since you wrote this, but is it in principle possible that the script would in your case first check that the image has not been loaded yet, so it would go into a body of an if-condition planning to register an onload event, but before it would have managed to do that, the image would just have been loaded meanwhile in the background, thus skipping the handler call for that image just due to a race condition? If yes, then your solution is fragile. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's an onload event. I wouldn't have thought that event would fire more than once.

You could attach your script to the body / document onload event and loop through all the images and attach your event handlers then, perhaps.

Comment: That works but the page loads slowly and the images need to be replaced as soon as possible

Comment: Another option would be to attach event handlers to the images in batches, before the page has finished loaded but after the images have loaded, by including scripts directly into the page. Don't know if that would work with Greasemonkey.

Comment: I've tried that but some images load before I can add the scripts

Answer (score -1):

I've just had the same issue and Google takes me there.

I didn't want to use jQuery, so I searched for another solution. In the end, in my case, I simply changed the image's "src" attribute to any dummy picture (e.g. 1pix.png) just before setting the right image in "src", to force a reload for each image. Of course, this is not a bright idea if you have large images and/or if you frequently load images... But in my case it's ok I guess, I only need to load the big actual image only once (moreover, I think that the underlying browser cache mechanism avoids a real image reloading...).

Hope it can help others!

PS: It seems to be near to @Bugster workaround but I didn't really understand it!

Comment: So you already have the images loaded and you force a reload? Do you see the problem here?

Comment: @BojidarStanchev I think you may have misunderstood: I don't have "the images" (plural) loaded. Just one (tiny image) is loaded, then I load the real one when I want to force the onload

Comment: "to force a reload for each image." - nothing more to say.

Comment: @BojidarStanchev Please explain clearly your point of view, because saying _"Do you see the problem here?"_ and quoting my comment and just adding _"nothing more to say"_ ... this is not what I call having a conversation :-/

Comment: Fair point, but I find it obvious that if you want a glass of water in your house you don't reinstall the sink to pour a glass of water. To be more clear - if you have already appended the images to the dom and they have indeed loaded you should check if they were already loaded and use them straight away instead of forcing a reload on each image. Reloading each image wastes execution time and possibly bandwidth if the browser hasnt cached the images. This will also cause people on mobile to run out of data and battery faster (theoretically, the inpact of this is based on the image volume).

Comment: For stationary devices, the problem will be only the slower load speed of the component.

Comment: I agree, this is not optimal at all. That's why my conclusion in my answer is _"in my case it's ok I guess"_ . That's also why I used a 1-pixel image as the initial image (in my answer I mentioned "e.g. 1pix.png"), so that the extra bandwidth should only be a few bytes. So yeah, more a hack/workaround than a solution, but except for the few extra bytes of bandwidth (that may be cached by the browser), this is a quick and easy (and dirty, I agree!) way to force an "onload" event.

Comment: the initial image is not the problem, loading the real image 2 times is. The extra bandwidth is the size of the real image + your few bytes from the 1px image. So if you have 1mb photos you have 1mb extra bandwidth per photo

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. In my case I only needed to force the refresh once, so I loaded the big image only once, so the extra bandwidth was really only the 1-pix image. I'll edit my answer to reflect that!

Comment: I see, also I hope you understand why I was being mean - someone new to web development might get easily misled into your solution and use it in the wrong place.

Comment: Agreed. No worries, I just had a hard time understanding your (good) point. Maybe next time try to be explicit and more clear right from the beginning ;-)